# iam getting an error in postman while performing login through api : { "non_field_errors": [ "Unable to log in with provided credentials." ] }

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

## ** here is my models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from .manager import CustomUserManager

STATE_CHOICES = (
    ('Odisha', 'Odisha'),
    ('Karnataka', 'Karnataka')
)
ROLES = (
    ('admin', 'admin'),
    ('customer', 'customer'),
    ('seller', 'seller'),
)

class User_role(models.Model):
    role = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)

class User_Profile(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    # role = models.CharField(choices=ROLES, max_length=50)
    role = models.ForeignKey(User_role, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']

    objects = CustomUserManager()

class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    selling_price = models.FloatField()
    discount_price = models.FloatField()
    description = models.TextField()
    productImg = models.ImageField(upload_to="productImages")

class Cart(models.Model):
    user_profile = models.ForeignKey(User_Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)

class Order_Placed(models.Model):
    user_profile = models.ForeignKey(User_Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)
    order_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

## **managers.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import BaseUserManager

class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, username, password=None, role=None, **extra_fields):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('The Email field must be set')
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, username=username, role=role, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, username, password=None, role=None, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)

        # Assign a default role for superusers
        if role is None:
            # role = 'admin'
            from .models import User_role
            role = User_role.objects.get(role='admin')

        return self.create_user(email, username, password, role, **extra_fields)
```

## **here is my serializers.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework import serializers, validators
from .models import *
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password 

class RegisterSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User_Profile
        fields = ('username','email','password','role')

        extra_kwargs = {
            "password": {"write_only": True},
            "email": {
                "required": True,
                "validators": [
                    validators.UniqueValidator(
                        User_Profile.objects.all(), "A user with that email already exists" 
                    )
                ]
            }
        }
    
    def create(self, validated_data):
        username = validated_data.get("username")
        email = validated_data.get("email")

        # Hashing the Password
        password = validated_data.get("password")
        # Hash the password using Django's password hasher
        hashed_password = make_password(password)
        # Update the validated_data with the hashed password
        validated_data['password'] = hashed_password
        password = hashed_password

        role = validated_data.get("role")
         # Check if the role is a string and convert it to an integer if needed
        if isinstance(role, str):
            role = int(role)

        user = User_Profile.objects.create(
            username= username,
            email= email,
            password= password,
            role = role
        )

        return user
```

## here is my views.py**

```
# user login API
@api_view(['POST']) 
def login_api(request):
    serializer = AuthTokenSerializer(data=request.data)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    user = serializer.validated_data['user']
    _, token = AuthToken.objects.create(user)
    return Response({
        'user_info': {
            'id': user.id,
            'username': user.username,
            'email': user.email
            },
        'token': token
    })

# get user data API
@api_view(['GET'])
def get_user_data(request):
    user = request.user

    if user.is_authenticated:
        return Response({
            'user_info': {
            'id': user.id,
            'username': user.username,
            'email': user.email
            },
    })

    return Response({'error':'not authenticated'},status=400)

# register user API
@api_view(['POST'])
def register_api(request):
    serializer = RegisterSerializers(data=request.data)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

    user = serializer.save()
    _, token = AuthToken.objects.create(user)

    return Response({
        'user_info': {
            'id': user.id,
            'username': user.username,
            'email': user.email
            },
        'token': token
        })
```

registration, logout are working fine on postman app but login is not working, it shows { "non_field_errors": [ "Unable to log in with provided credentials." ] }

the data is saving perfectly in the admin panel

and also the token are saved perfectly

please help me...